# jQuery: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been transferring this script (http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FHZBy/) in to my live environment within a CS Cart install but I am receiving an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` message and the script isn't running.

I'm not sure what is causing the error, would be grateful if you could check it out at: http://mtpassemblies.com/cs-cart/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=29821 and let me know, I'm sure it is probably something very simple that I've overlooked but can' seem to pinpoint the problem.

I've checked to make sure my jQuery is up to date as read that sometimes a corrupt file will cause this error but that doesn't seem to be the case as I'm referencing the js file at the jquery codebase.

The following is the code that is within the page that should be building a product SKU when the user selects various options:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(function() {
var sku1 = sku2 = sku3 = sku4 = sku5 = sku6 = length = '';
$("#opt_29821_746").live('change',function(){

    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3134":
             sku1 = 'TB';
        break;
        case "3135":
             sku1 = 'LT';
        break;
        case "3154":
            sku1 = 'LTR';
        break;
        case "3136":
             sku1 = 'BO';
        break;
        case "3138":
             sku1 = 'MC';
        break;
        case "3139":
             sku1 = 'NC';
        break;
        case "3183":
              sku1 = 'STA';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});
$("#opt_29821_742").live('change',function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3111":
              sku2 = 'LC';
        break;
        case "3110":
             sku2 ='LCA';
        break;
        case "3112":
             sku2 ='E2000';
        break;
        case "3113":
             sku2 ='E2A';
        break;
        case "3114":
             sku2 ='FC';
        break;
        case "3115":
             sku2 ='FCA';
        break;
        case "3116":
             sku2 ='ST';
        break;
        case "3117":
             sku2 ='SC';
        break;
        case "3118":
             sku2 ='SCA';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});
$("#opt_29821_744").live('change',function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3175":
              sku3 = '2';
        break;
        case "3121":
             sku3 ='4';
        break;
        case "3122":
             sku3 ='6';
        break;
        case "3123":
             sku3 ='8';
        break;
        case "3124":
             sku3 ='12';
        break;
        case "3125":
             sku3 ='16';
        break;
        case "3126":
             sku3 ='24';
        break;
        case "3176":
             sku3 ='48';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});

$("#opt_29821_745").live('change',function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3127":
              sku4 = 'OS12';
        break;
        case "3182":
             sku4 ='G657A1';
        break;
        case "3128":
             sku4 ='OM1';
        break;
        case "3129":
             sku4 ='OM2';
        break;
        case "3130":
             sku4 ='OM3';
        break;
        case "3131":
             sku4 ='OM4';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});

$("#opt_29821_748").live('change',function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3142":
              sku5 = 'LC';
        break;
        case "3143":
             sku5 ='LCA';
        break;
        case "3144":
             sku5 ='E2000';
        break;
        case "3145":
             sku5 ='E2A';
        break;
        case "3146":
             sku5 ='FC';
        break;
        case "3147":
             sku5 ='FCA';
        break;
        case "3148":
             sku5 ='ST';
        break;
        case "3149":
             sku5 ='SC';
        break;
        case "3150":
             sku5 ='SCA';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});

$("#opt_29821_749").live('change',function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3151":
              sku5 = 'LZSH';
        break;
        case "3177":
             sku5 ='PE';
        break;
    }
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});

$('#opt_29821_753').live('change',function(){
    length = $(this).val();
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});
​    });
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a non-printable unicode character present on the line flagged by Console. Since it is not "visible" I cannot tell you exactly what character it is. Try removing all white-space on near the end of your script, then add it back:

```
    $('#option_29821_798').val(sku1+sku2+sku3+sku4+sku5+sku6+length);
});
// ^---- that character is here    
    });
```

Comment: No, unfortunately! have a look - http://mtpassemblies.com/cs-cart/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=29821 - if you have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FHZBy/ you'll see that the sku/partnumber box should build up dependant on what choice the user makes.